# Failed image loading in Stencil Theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a background image that fails to load in a BigCommerce Stencil theme only once the theme is deployed.

I am loading the image via CSS:

background-image: url(/assets/img/backgrounds/background_flag@700x394@72ppi.jpg);

The final URL outputted:
http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/assets/img/backgrounds/background_flag@700x394@72ppi.jpg (not found)

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure why your URL doesn't have a store identifier after bigcommerce.com

Comment: The original advice given actually fix this, for anyone else having this issue. Use '../' and then stencilString to move the image name into the config.